# is widevine supported for 64 bit pi-os

Tags: pi-4

I'm using the official 64bit version of pi-os but widevine

in the form of

sudo apt install libwidevinecdm0

doesn't make it available in chromium  is it available? for 64bit

Comment: According to https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=347736 it should be available

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Better Chromium, or remove both libwidevinecdm0 and chromium first, then reinstall chromium then libwidevinecdm0 in that order. Netflix on 64bit PI OS is fine.

However, if you're also using Spotify, there seems to be an issue with Widevine as of this writing on 64bit Chromium and 64-bit PI OS. Playback on Spotify Web or even in the Chromium App kind of just skips tracks, then plays a song after a few tracks but only partway, then skips again, and loops on this behavior. I have not yet been able to fix this, so I reinstalled the 32-bit Pi OS again (using it right now as I'm writing this) so that I can use both Netflix on Chromium and Spotify Chromium App. Both now works fine.

Netflix video playback is passable for the most part with 32bit, but seems to be "blocky" or tearing especially when there are panning or fast scenes (I'm on Ethernet and have the 720p playback subscription at 3440x1440 fullscreen, over only 200Mbps fiber). Locally saved 1080p 60Hz video playback with VLC is fine (using ArgonOne M.2 case with M.2 SATA SSD).

I would recommend using 32bit PI OS for now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  Carla H. This explains the problem as well as a possible solution. I'm using 644 bit because my printer only has 64bit support so am a bit stuck. When Pi's are available I might try with 32bit

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was installing the 32 bit version of both Chromium and libwidevinecdm0. So first removing them both and then:

sudo apt install chromium-browser:armhf

sudo apt-get install libwidevinecdm0:armhf

Comment: good work around but I think I'll wait for pi os to upgrade as i don't want rto down grade the browser!